# When is a maximum matching also a perfect matching for graphs with perfect matching?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

If there is a perfect matching of a graph then does it mean every maximum matching is automatically a perfect matching?

Comment: Do you mean maximal rather than maximum (i.e. a matching that can't be extended, rather than one whose cardinality is as large as possible)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael it would be maximum or else the problem would be trivial

Comment: No, "maximum" makes the problem trivial: if there is a perfect matching, that is automatically a maximum matching, and every maximum matching is a perfect matching.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you mean to say that whenever any graph has a perfect matching then any maximum matching is a perfect matching. I proved it by contradiction. Let's say that graph has perfect matching P but we have a maximum matching M which is not perfect then clearly P must have more cardinality than M(since no matching can be larger than |V|/2 and P is precisely of this size) which contradicts that M was maximum. Is this argument fair? [Note: V denotes the vertex set of the graph]

Answer (score 3):

No, and not even for bipartite graphs where each part has $n$ vertices.  For example, consider this bipartite graph

[image]

EDIT: In the following graph, there is a perfect matching $\{(1,3), (2,4)\}$, but the matching $\{(1,4)\}$ is **maximal**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but updated problem more precisely

Answer (score 0):

No, those conditions are way too weak.

There are two very famous characterizations for when a graph has a perfect matching.

The first is for general graphs, and is called [Tutte's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem)

The second one is for bipartite graphs and is called [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem)

Comment: is there an algebraic way to portray this rather than combinatorial way?

Comment: do you mean a way to find if a graph has a perfect mathcing from some of its matrices? I don't know.

Comment: I like your answer but I am looking for something more subtle than this